# How can we make the BroadcastReceiver respond when the Checkbox in the activity is enabled?

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, broadcastreceiver

I'm a newbie in Android.Here, I have a Checkbox in my Activity. What I  actually want is, on enabling the Checkbox ,my BroadcastReceiver needs to respond. So for that what do I do? How is it done.

Can anyone give a sample code for doing that?

Can you please tell me whether I can do this:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

....
.....
.....
 //Check a condition and if its true declare a BroadcastReceiver like this here

class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean checking by 'enabling'? If so catch the event and then broadcast whatever you need.

Comment: save the check box values in preferences and check it in broadcast receiver...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if(_cb.isChecked()){
  startService(serviceIntent);
  registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(YourService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
}else{
  stopService(serviceIntent);
  unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

and post your code..

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of like asking "How do I make my telephone ring when I turn on the television?". Of course the answer here is that something must be monitoring the television and, when it comes on, must dial your telephone number. Or, in your case, you need to have a listener that is called when your checkbox is checked, and in response it must broadcast an Intent whose action and filters match what your broadcast receiver is configured to receive.